# Wordpress curl google curl request

Tags: wordpress, curl, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display business hours on a single post page using a Google API CURL Request.  This worked outside of wordpress, but gets an "INVALID_REQUEST" error when in Wordpress.  I added the following code to my content.php page.  When I tried this with the WP_Http class, I had the same error.

```
               $ch = curl_init();
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
              'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='.get_field('google_place_id').'8&key=AIzaSyBsFOzP0Xg7b1GgK3x09l_isAiLUTWwS2g');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);

                print_r($result);
                $json_a=json_decode($result,true);

                  $now = $json_a[result][opening_hours][open_now];
                    if ($now == 1) { print "Currently: Open" . '<br/><br/>'; } else { print "Currently: Closed" . '<br/><br/>'; }

                  $hours = $json_a[result][opening_hours][weekday_text];

                    foreach ($hours as $v) {
                        echo $v . '<br/>';
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a  `8` before `&key`, this probably will make the `placeid` invalid.